# Python logging in multiprocessing: AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'flush'

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

Based on this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916874) I created a python object that both prints output to the terminal and saves the output to a log file with the date and time appended to its name:

```
import sys
import time

class Logger(object):
    """
    Creates a class that will both print and log any
    output text. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916874
    for original source code. Modified to add date and
    time to end of file name.
    """
    def __init__(self, filename="Default"):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.filename = filename + ' ' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') + '.txt'
        self.log = open(self.filename, "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)


sys.stdout = Logger('TestLog')
```

This works great, but when I try to use it with a script that uses the `Pool` multiprocessing function, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'flush'
```

How can I modify my `Logger` object so that it will work with any script that runs in parallel?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're replacing `sys.stdout`, it must be with a [file-like object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects), which means you have to implement `flush`.  [`flush` can be a no-op](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush):

```
def flush(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Generally `file-like` does *not* mean that it *must* implement `flush()`. In almost all contexts `file-like` either means that it has a `readline()`/`read()` method (in case the file is an input that is read), or that it has to implement the `write()` method (if it's used to output stuff). In this case most libraries assume `sys.stdout` is a real file, since logging is usually performed without replacing `sys.stdout`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Is there a better way to both log the text and print it in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

@ecatmur's answer will only fix the missing flush, once this is added I receive:

```
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

A comment in the post for the [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916874/3991139) provides a modification which will account for any additional missing attributes, for completeness I will post the full working version of this code:

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename = "logfile.log"):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.terminal, attr)

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

This runs for me without error in Python 2.7. Have not tested in 3.3+.

Answer (score 0):

If the flush is not implemented, it won't work, find below a detailed answer with flush implemented.

```
import sys
import logging

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open(filename, "a")
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.terminal, attr)
    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)      
    def flush(self):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.log.flush()
```

I was experiencing issues without the flushing the logs.
Then, it can be used as follow:

```
sys.stdout = Logger("file.log")
```